# The New Navigation for the SO Blog is Hidden in the Header

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

I like the new design for the SO blog, but I the navigation is hidden behind the header:

[image]

I would think this would be a simple CSS fix, but I am not sure.

Here is my environment:

- macOS 10.12.6
- Google Chrome 60.0.3112.113

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed. The blog was injecting CSS from the topbar changes that were unexpected.

Comment: Well that took considerably less than 6-8 weeks... ggwp!